# Migrate persistent store to new location

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to move my app's database to a new location and stop it from being shared through iCloud automatically.

From my understanding, Apple previously documented that a database should be placed in the Documents directory of an application, but now says that the database should be placed in the Library directory.  This is because iOS now shares all data from the Documents directory through iCloud.

My issue is that I need to move my database from the Documents directory to the Library directory. Below is the code I use to do this.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    // Get the URL of the persistent store
    NSURL *oldURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"App.sqlite"];
    bool oldStoreExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[oldURL path]];

    // Get the URL of the new App Group location
    NSURL *newURL = [[self applicationLibraryDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"App.sqlite"];
    bool shouldMoveStore = false;

    NSURL *storeURL = nil;
    if (!oldStoreExists) {
        //There is no store in the old location
        storeURL = newURL;
    } else {
        storeURL = oldURL;
        shouldMoveStore = true;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES };
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error Moving Store: %ld\nDescription: %@\nReason: %@\nSuggested Fix:%@", (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion);
        abort();
    }

    if (shouldMoveStore)
        [self movePersistentStoreFrom:oldURL To:newURL];

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

```
-(void) movePersistentStoreFrom:(NSURL *)oldURL To:(NSURL *)newURL {
    // Get the reference to the current persistent store
    NSPersistentStore *oldStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:oldURL];
    // Migrate the persistent store
    NSError *error = nil;
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:oldStore toURL:newURL options:nil withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error Moving Store: %ld\nDescription: %@\nReason: %@\nSuggested Fix:%@", (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion);
        abort();
    }
}
```

This code seems to work in moving the persistent store, but on the next run of the application the old store is found again and the app attempts to migrate the store a second time.  At this point a crash occurs, and I'm assuming it is due to this double migration call.  In classic Xcode style, the stack trace is pretty much useless.

Update -
The migratePersistentStore function does not remove ("cut/paste") the old sqlite database, instead it just makes a "copy".  It looks like I'll need to remove the old one programmatically.

I switched the code to check if the newStoreExists as opposed to the !oldStoreExists, and the migration does work.

My new issue is that the table rows of the migrated data have become randomized.  Any help with this would be appreciated!

Update 2 -
As it turns out, any data migrations like moving the store location or updating the database will randomize your data if you are using Core Data. You need to put an attribute into your table and use a NSSortDescriptor inside of your NSFetchRequest to manually sort the data and keep it ordered.

If you never migrate the data (I previously had not) the core data fetch request always come in the order it was saved.